# iptables NAT with multiple internet interfaces

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

Now I have three network interfaces, `eth0`, `eth1` and `eth2`.

```
eth0: 45.1.1.1, connect directly to the internet
eth1: 192.168.11.1, the gateway before the router
eth2: 45.1.1.2, connect directly to the internet
```

in the router I have two interfaces:

```
192.168.11.2 for traffics from eth0
192.168.11.3 for traffic from eth2
```

I need to redirect traffics from `eth0` and `eth2` to `eth1`, and I have the following rules:

```sh
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.11.2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.11.3

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.11.2 -j SNAT --to-source 45.1.1.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.11.3 -j SNAT --to-source 45.1.1.2
```

after testing, I found that machines behind `192.168.11.3` can't connect to internet, but the other one can. Is something wrong with my rules?

Comment: Set lower AD/metric to the exit route you want and that's it.

Comment: should I lower eth0 and eth2?

Comment: Hm...your rules don't look too good, it's best you should rebuild them from scratch. There is no PREROUTING -i eth2, but you have a PREROUTING -i eth0; that's a difference between the 2.